# IBM FEB forms are not loading on android devices

Tags: android, forms, webview, android-webview

We are showing IBM FEB forms in a WebViewOverlay in our mobile app. These forms load in the application on all iOS devices but not in Android. Is there any settings on FEB that we need to enable to open forms in WebView in Android?

Comment: Logs from LogCat...? Maybe there is an error there? You will also want to direct that question to the IBM FEB team instead first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Overlay does not behave exactly like the default browser in android. To make it work for all versions of Android update below parameters in WebViewOverlay code.

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" +
webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
}
```